# How to secure Cloudfront to Beanstalk traffic

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudfront

I'm using the following setup:

- Custom DNS provider (not Route 53)
- Elastic Beanstalk: myapp.region.elasticbeanstalk.com
- Cloudfront with myapp.com as CNAME

Cloudfront currently grabs the content from myapp.region.elasticbeanstalk.com. But because of this, the following server vars are set:

```
HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO  http
HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PORT   80
```

So to encrypt the whole chain, I would register another CNAME:

- ebs.myapp.com --> myapp.region.elasticbeanstalk.com
- Adding a SSL certificate to ebs.myapp.com
- Cloudfront origin: ebs.myapp.com, HTTPS only
- Cloudfront cname: myapp.com, Redirect HTTP to HTTPS

Does this make any sense? Or are there easier ways to do this?

Comment: Umpf, sorry, Amazon CloudFront!

Comment: Those HTTP headers have nothing to do with where cloudfront is grabbing the content from. Those are telling you that the client (the web browser) is connecting over HTTP, not HTTPS. You would need to add an SSL cert to your Cloudfront distribution and enable HTTP->HTTPS forwarding to encrypt all communication with the end user. The backend ssl config you describe is optional if you want SSL between CF and EB.